# How to set default link with javascript?

Tags: javascript, focus

I try set a default link in a modal, but not working (I am very new in javascript).

This is my full code:

```
    <a href="#my-id" data-uk-modal="{center:true}"></a>
    <button class="md-btn md-btn-success" id="openmodal" data-uk-modal="{target:'#my_id', keyboard: false, bgclose: false}" style="display:none !important;"></button>

    <div class="uk-modal" id="my_id">  
       <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
           <div class="uk-modal-header">
              <div uk-grid class="uk-grid">
                <div class="modal-block">
                 <h3>Project</h3>
    <b>project description, lorem ipsum... <a href="https://www.instagram.com/user/">instagram</a></b>
             </div>
               <div class="modal-block">
               <h3>Terms</h3>
    <b>terms description</b>
              </div>
               <div class="modal-block">
                <h3>Cookies</h3>
    <b>cookies description</b>
               </div>
           </div>
         </div>

                    <div class="uk-modal-footer uk-clearfix">
                    <a id="default-link" uk-tooltip="{title: okay, i accept!; pos: bottom}" class="us--main-button uk-float-right entersite uk-modal-close" href="javascript:void(0)">Accept and enter</a>
                    <a  id="dont-def" uk-tooltip="{title: I do not agree!; pos: bottom}" class="us--leave-button uk-float-right" href="https://google.com">Deny and leave</a>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#openmodal').trigger('click');
    })  
    </script>
    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
       document.getElementById("default-link").focus();
    };
    </script>
```

When I open the page in any browser, the default stated link will be the first (instagram)... Whats the wrong with this?

Comment: The posted code works, which either mean the browser you tried does not, or code is missing that make it not.

Comment: I updated my question... not working even in any browser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code works when it comes to give the link focus, though if one hit enter (or click on it) nothing will happen since you've cancelled its action with `href="javascript:void(0)"`

Here is a sample that shows that the `focus()` does work.

Click "Run code snippet" and hit "Enter" and you'll get an alert.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("default-link").focus();
};
```

```html
<div class="uk-modal" id="my_id">
  <div class="modal-block">
    lorem ipsum... <a href="https://www.instagram.com/user/">instagram</a>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a id="default-link" class="uk-modal-close" href="javascript:alert('Accept')">Accept and enter</a>
    <a class="uk-float-right" href="https://google.com">Deny cookies and leave</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated my question with the full code, because it does not work... Now here are everything... I try with  `href="javascript:alert('Accept')"`, but also dont working :/

Comment: @GalgócziLevente Try and move your `document.getElementById("default-link").focus();` so it runs after `$('#openmodal').trigger('click');` ...and your updated code still works when adding `href="javascript:alert('Accept')"` to the link

Comment: not working... I try in 20 different combination now in three different browser... :S Very frustrating

Comment: @GalgócziLevente Since the existing code works here in the Stack snippet, we can't do much. You need to provide a code snippet that actually fails here as well.

Comment: wow, now working! I dont do anything with this part in my code in the last few hours, I worked on an another part, but now, a few minutes ago started working... weird... :D

Comment: @GalgócziLevente Sounds great

Answer (score -1):

I just now find out the really best solution for that, because the window.onload to slow, and when the site loading, the default link is over the first link in the current page...

So the best the html5 solution, very simple, and this really makes default from your any item, independently from the page or document loading:

```
<div autofocus>
```

Comment: `autofocus` does not work on a `div`, it works only on _form_ elements such as e.g. an `input`.